# Putting variables from Function workspace to base workspace

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, workspace

I have a script calling a function, calling a function to simulate a model. The 2nd function also loads variables that the simulink model Needs for lookuptables. Now if I run it, matlab tells me, it doesn't know those variables. So I assume, that the variables have to be in base-workspace for simulink to recognise them and I tried to call

```
vars=whos;
for k_laden=1:length(vars)
assignin('base', vars(k_laden).name, eval(vars(k_laden).name))
end
```

in the 2nd function, but then matlab tells me

> ??? The variable "ans" is undefined.
>
> Error in ==> esm6 at 76
>               assignin('base', vars(k_laden).name, eval(vars(k_laden).name))
>
> Error in ==> Optimierung_Querdynamik_MBT at 87
>           y = esm6(param_komplett,identi);
>
> Error in ==> Identi at 176
>                   [param_plotten , guete_wert] = Optimierung_Querdynamik_MBT(ESM_Wahl,Plotten,param_plotten,identi);

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
the variables that simulink Needs, are created by the load-command. So it might help if you give me a way to call the load command from a function but directly loading the variables into base-workspace.
Also it might help, if i could define which Workspace the simulink model is using.

Comment: As a general aside, if your variables are all coming from `load`, I highly recommend [specifying an output argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#zmw57dd0e431624), which will place your variables into a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) and remove the need for `eval`

Comment: the .mat-files that i usually load, are all consisting of 4 structures and i don't want to have these 4 structures combined in a single structure. Thank you anyway, general coding adive is always appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Simulink looks in the base workspace, but assuming that you are simulating the model by using the `sim` function within your function, then just define the variables in the functions workspace and use

```
sim('modelname','SrcWorkspace','current');
```

Comment: looks like what i was looking for. I'll give you feedback if it's working after the holidays. So far thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but this solved my Problem! Thank you :)